# ¿Cómo puedo buscar el ID de un usuario para utilizarlo como parametro en un insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que necesito hacer es ver de que forma puedo utilizar el id de la tabla **USUARIO** en el campo **ID_USR** DE LA TABLA **ATLETA** para que cumpla la funci[on de foreign key. En caso de que no lo haga de esa forma el código para insertar atletas tendría que verse algo así:

```
CALL SP_ATLETA_INSERTAR(1, 1, 'Iván Coto Jiménez', '305450485', '2003', 'In Neh Kwan', '-68', 'M', 'K', '+50685592166', 'ivancototkd@gmail.com', 'ELITE');
```

Donde básicamente los primeros digitos son el ID_ACADEMIA Y ID_USR respectivamente.

```
/*(ID_ACADEMIA, ID_USR, NOMBRE_AT, CEDULA_AT, ANO_NAC_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT, CAT_PESO_AT, SEXO_AT, CATEGORIA_AT, NUM_TEL_AT, EMAIL_AT, CINT_CAT_AT)*/
```

**TABLA USUARIO**

```
CREATE TABLE `USUARIO`(
     ID_USUARIO INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     USUARIO_USR VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     EMAIL_USR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     CEDULA_USR VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     NOMBRE_USR VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
     PASS_USR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_USUARIO
     PRIMARY KEY(ID_USUARIO)
);
```

**TABLA ATLETA**

```
CREATE TABLE `ATLETA`(
     ID_ATLETA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ID_ACADEMIA INT NOT NULL, /*FOREIGN KEY*/
     ID_USR INT NOT NULL, /*FOREIGN KEY*/
     NOMBRE_AT VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
     CEDULA_AT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     ANO_NAC_AT VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     NOM_ACADEMIA_AT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     CAT_PESO_AT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     SEXO_AT CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     CATEGORIA_AT CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     NUM_TEL_AT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     EMAIL_AT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     CINT_CAT_AT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT CKC_ATLETA_SEXO
     CHECK (SEXO_AT IN ('M', 'F')),
     CONSTRAINT CKC_ATLETA_CATEGORIA
     CHECK (CATEGORIA_AT IN ('K', 'P', 'PP', 'PE')),
     CONSTRAINT PK_ATLETA
     PRIMARY KEY(ID_ATLETA),
     CONSTRAINT FK_ATLETA_ACADEMIA
     FOREIGN KEY(ID_ACADEMIA)
     REFERENCES ACADEMIA(ID_ACA),
     CONSTRAINT FK_ATLETA_USUARIO
     FOREIGN KEY(ID_USR)
     REFERENCES USUARIO(ID_USUARIO)
);
```

**PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO PARA INCLUIR ATLETAS**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ATLETA_INSERTAR(
IN ID_ACADEMIA INT,
ID_USR INT,
NOMBRE_AT VARCHAR(60),
CEDULA_AT VARCHAR(20),
ANO_NAC_AT VARCHAR(5),
NOM_ACADEMIA_AT VARCHAR(100),
CAT_PESO_AT VARCHAR(10),
SEXO_AT CHAR(1),
CATEGORIA_AT CHAR(1),
NUM_TEL_AT VARCHAR(30),
EMAIL_AT VARCHAR(100),
CINT_CAT_AT VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXISTE INT;
SET EXISTE = (SELECT ID_ACA FROM ACADEMIA WHERE ID_ACA=ID_ACADEMIA);
    IF(SEXO_AT = 'M' OR SEXO_AT = 'F') AND (CATEGORIA_AT = 'K' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'P' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'PP' OR CATEGORIA_AT = 'PE' AND EXISTE IS NOT NULL) THEN 
    INSERT INTO ATLETA (ID_ACADEMIA, ID_USR, NOMBRE_AT, CEDULA_AT, ANO_NAC_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT, CAT_PESO_AT, SEXO_AT, CATEGORIA_AT, NUM_TEL_AT, EMAIL_AT, CINT_CAT_AT) VALUES (ID_ACADEMIA, ID_USR, NOMBRE_AT, CEDULA_AT, ANO_NAC_AT, NOM_ACADEMIA_AT, CAT_PESO_AT, SEXO_AT, CATEGORIA_AT, NUM_TEL_AT, EMAIL_AT, CINT_CAT_AT);
   END IF;
END//
```